# Python 3. How to access the dictionary of a running one from another module?

Tags: python

I have a ready Flask server where nlp models are run. While 5 devices were connected to it, there were no problems, then we increased this number to 15 and then the performance problem began. We decided to increase the number of cores on this server from 12 to 24, but got a performance increase of around 20%. We decided to try another method, launched 3 servers via Gunicorn and taskset --cpu-list (giving 8 cores to each server) on different ports with a limit of 5 devices per server, here the performance almost doubled, became approximately the same as on a server with 12 cores when there were 5 devices. But then another problem arose, each server ran its models in isolation from each other and RAM consumption increased by 3 times.

Models are loaded into the dictionary by this code

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import os
import learning

app = Flask(__name__)

models_list_name = os.listdir('models')

global_dict_models = {}

for token in models_list_name:
    try:
        tok, n_class, model_type, typ, h_layer = token.split('.')

        t, model = learning.get_model(model_type, typ)

        n_class = int(n_class)
        h_layer = int(h_layer)
        model = learning.NewModel(model, n_class, typ, h_layer)
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join('models', token), map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
        
        print(model, tok)
        with open(tok, 'r') as f:
            label = f.read().split('\n')
        print(label)
        global_dict_models[tok] = (t, model, label)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

and when a predict is needed, the query simply accesses the dictionary

```
t, model, labels = global_dict_models[token]
x = t.encode_plus(text, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512, truncation=True, padding="max_length", return_tensors='pt')
    
output = torch.sigmoid(model(x['input_ids'].squeeze(1), x['attention_mask'])).detach().cpu().numpy()
```

Models on all servers are the same. I want to make a single module with model loading, where a dictionary is formed and so that each server would simply access it through a function.

I tried to create a separate module according to this principle

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import os
import learning

app = Flask(__name__)

models_list_name = os.listdir('models')

global_dict_models = {}

def load_models():
    for token in models_list_name:
        try:
            tok, n_class, model_type, typ, h_layer = token.split('.')
    
            t, model = learning.get_model(model_type, typ)
    
            n_class = int(n_class)
            h_layer = int(h_layer)
            model = learning.NewModel(model, n_class, typ, h_layer)
            model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join('models', token), map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
            
            print(model, tok)
            with open(tok, 'r') as f:
                label = f.read().split('\n')
            print(label)
            global_dict_models[tok] = (t, model, label)
        except ValueError:
            pass
  

def dict_models(token):
    t, model, labels = global_dict_models[token]
    return t, model, labels    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_models()
    print('Start')
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="5000", threaded=True, processes=1)
```

And then a problem arose that it was impossible to read a dictionary that was launched in another module.

Tell me how to load the dictionary once and have access to it from other modules? Or how to solve this problem in another way?

Comment: you can't access it directly. You may use socket or flask request to access data in other server. OR you may write in file in one server and read file in other server. I never tried but there is also module standard module for [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html)

Comment: @furas Tested options with shared memory. 1) It is also loaded into the RAM when called, it only loads the necessary part of the dictionary, and not the whole one, it would be possible to be satisfied with this option if it were not slow, the prediction response increased by almost 1 second. 2) Through the manager, the RAM consumption decreased by 2 times, in general, I did not understand the essence of his work, but instead of 3GB of memory for 2 models, he began to consume 1.8GB. And here, too, the prediction response increased by almost a second.